# How to avoid session timeout in Android

Tags: android, session, video-streaming, jsch

In my Android application am showing live video streaming using `LibVLC` library. To connect **SSH** server i have used `jsch` library.

When i run application, after session connection video runs properly. and when i minimize the app for 3-4 minutes, and resume again still video runs properly. But when i minimize the application for 10 or more minutes and on resume it shows `session timeout` message.

`OnResume()` I tried to create session and `createPlayer()` but still not working .

I have tried by changing session connect time.

Is there is any way to avoid session timeout for long period like 30 minutes.

//** AFTER EDIT**//

I checked after `onResume()` session is still connected, and error log says `Connection reset by peer.`

What does that mean? Is ssh tunnel is closed? If yes, how to check ssh tunnel status?

**Error log:**

> 08-09 10:52:15.268 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample E/VLC: live555 demux: Failed to connect with rtsp://localhost:8554/video.ts
>   08-09 10:52:15.268 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample D/VLC: core demux: no access_demux modules matched
>   08-09 10:52:15.268 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample D/VLC: core input: creating access 'rtsp' location='localhost:8554/video.ts', path='(null)'
>   08-09 10:52:15.268 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample D/VLC: core access: looking for access module matching "rtsp": 15 candidates
>   08-09 10:52:15.268 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample D/VLC: core access: net: connecting to localhost port 8554
>   08-09 10:52:15.278 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample D/VLC: core access: connection succeeded (socket = 36)
>   08-09 10:52:35.823 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample E/VLC: core access: read error: Connection reset by peer
>   08-09 10:52:35.823 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample D/VLC: access_realrtsp access: rtsp connected
>   08-09 10:52:35.823 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample W/VLC: access_realrtsp access: only real/helix rtsp servers supported for now
>   08-09 10:52:35.823 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample D/VLC: core access: no access modules matched
>   08-09 10:52:35.823 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample E/VLC: core input: open of rtsp://localhost:8554/video.ts' failed
>   08-09 10:52:35.823 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample E/VLC: core input: Your input can't be opened
>   08-09 10:52:35.823 6529-21339/com.compdigitec.libvlcandroidsample E/VLC: core input: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://localhost:8554/video.ts'

Comment: I would recommend that instead of changing the timeout, you implement a mechanism that automatically reconnects whenever your app resumes. You can never be 100% certain that your network connection will stay open for that long - just think of the user changing from one Wifi to another or losing connection temporarily.

Comment: I have added a code to reconnect with session, but it shows me Demux error

Comment: It sounds like you are getting a different error now. I would suggest you post the relevant part of your code and the exact error / exception.

Answer (score 1):

The demux error you are getting is happening at a higher level in the stack. You need to first validate that the underlying SSH connection is still good. To do so, check and if necessary reconnect when your application resumes:

```
public void onResume() {
    if (!session.isConnected()) {
        reconnect(); // needs to create a new session, open a channel, etc.
    }
}
```

Once you have validated the SSH connection, you should be able to resume the stream via LibVLC. If however you still see an error at that point, you'll have to show the code that you use to open / resume the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are opening a new stream, when you already have an existing stream opened.
Put a check to create a new stream only when the older stream is disconnected.

Following link might add some help:

https://github.com/bastimeyer/livestreamer-twitch-gui/issues/181

Answer (score 0):

```
     public void onResume() {
      if (!session.isConnected()) {
     reconnect(); // needs to create a new session, open a channel, etc.
    }
       }
```